# zip x number of arrays

Tags: python, arrays

I have a program graphing a huge list of numbers, and it may not be the most pythonic, but it works. I have 3 main arrays my X, Y, and Y error. Each of those arrays has sub arrays however:

```
xAxis = [[x1],[x2],[x3],[...]
yAxis = [[y1],[y2],[y3],[...]]
yError = [[err1],[err2],[err3],[...]]
```

and in this instance I graph anywhere from 1 to 6 y values against `xAxis[0]` and have an equal number of `yErrors`

I then use the `matrix2latex` package. This is the tough part because `matrix2latex` requires each array going into a table to be zipped.

I would like to avoid:

```
if howManyY == 1:
        zip(xAxis[0],yAxis[0],yError[0])
if howManyY == 2:
        zip(xAxis[0],yAxis[0],yAxis[1],yError[0],yError[1])
```

ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you need?

```
zip(*([xAxis[0]] + yAxis[:howManyY] + yError[:howManyY]))
```

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! This is very similar to what Valentin CLEMENT put, but then he deleted his answer

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
zipArgs = [ xAxis[0] ]
zipArgs.extend([ yAxis[i] for i in xrange(howManyY) ])
zipArgs.extend([ yError[i] for i in xrange(howManyY) ])
zip(*zipArgs)
```

The [asterisk operator](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) turns a list or tuple into positional arguments to a function.

Comment: This gives a different order than my original code above. I'm not too sure why, but I did try that as well. My result ends up being `[[xvalues],[y1values],[y2values],[yerror1valeus],[yerror2values]]` not `[(x,y1,y2,e1,e2),(x,y1,y2,e1,e2)]`